# matplotlib animation produces a blank

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a bunch of PNGs that I want to turn into an animation.  I use matplotlib for this.  I can display the resulting animation on the screen and everything looks fine.  But the saved MP4 is just a blank.  I mean I can play it, but it just shows a white, featureless window.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
import pylab as pyl
import matplotlib.pyplot as pplt
import matplotlib.image as mplimg
import matplotlib.animation as mplanim

myimages = []

for k in range(1,100):
    fname = "data{0:03d}.png".format(k)
    img = mplimg.imread(fname)
    imgplot = pplt.imshow(img)
    myimages.append([imgplot])

fig = pyl.figure()

myanim = mplanim.ArtistAnimation(fig, myimages, interval=20,
                                  blit=True, repeat_delay=1000)


myanim.save("anim.mp4", fps=10)

pyl.show()
```

UPDATE:  Moving `fig = pyl.figure()` to the top of the code, right after the imports solves the problem.  If anyone knows why, feel free to tell!  Thanks.

Comment: Try setting `blit=False`.

Comment: @Mike Muller  Thanks, but the result is the same.

Comment: Just use [FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)  directly `ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i data%03d.png -r 10 `

Comment: between this and your last question I suspect you want to be using `FuncAnimation` on what ever code is generating the images you are trying to stitch together here.

Comment: `fig = pyl.figure()`creates a new figure while `pplt.imshow(img)` added the image to the current plot axes that belongs to the default figure. Moving `fig = pyl.figure()` to the front makes it the default figure.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I face a similar problem on "matplotlib animation produces a blank".

Sometimes the matplotlib version can also lead to the blank outputs.

I solve it by downgrade from 3.7.1 to 3.4.1

In particular, it shows ``ax.lines this Attribute can not be set''. (I guess it maybe removed in the latest version?)

Answer (score -2):

Correct this line:

```
myimages.append([imgplot])
```

into:

```
myimages.append(imgplot)
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts.  However, it didn't like that at all.  ArtistAnimation returns an error "TypeError: 'AxesImage' object is not iterable"