# Matplotlib : Live animation works fine but displays a blank plot when being saved

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg, cellular-automata

I made a little forest fire animation. My code is at the end of the question.

Here is some information before I ask my question :

- No tree : `forest[i,j] = 0`
- A tree : `forest[i,j] = 1`
- A tree on fire : `forest[i,j] = 2`

Basically what happens is that `constructforest` creates a 2 dimensional array called `forest` of size **n** by **m** with a probability of tree occupancy called **p**. After that `setonfire` sets on fire the `forest` and while the `forest` can burn `spreadfire` spread the fire.

When I run `forestfire` with the `Python prompt` or the `IPython prompt` I get a nice animation but when I go check the video file that I saved I only see a blank plot.

I did some research, I found many questions about this issue but none of the advice I read was helpful:

- [matplotlib animation produces a blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028968/matplotlib-animation-produces-a-blank)
- [Matplotlib animation not working in IPython Notebook (blank plot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333732/matplotlib-animation-not-working-in-ipython-notebook-blank-plot)
- [Animation from matplotlib not working in spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856079/animation-from-matplotlib-not-working-in-spyder)
- [Spyder Python Animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816352/spyder-python-animation-not-working)

Can someone tell me what is going on please ?

#### forestfire.py

```
from random import random

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def hazard(p):
    r=random()
    assert p>=0 and p<=1
    return r <= p


def constructforest(n,m,p):
    forest = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(m):
            if hazard(p):
                forest[i,j] = 1
    return forest


def setfire(forest,i,j):
    forest[i,j] = 2
    return forest


def spreadfire(forest):    

    n,m=forest.shape
    c = np.copy(forest)

    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(m):

            if c[i,j] == 1:

                Y, X = xrange(max(0,i-1),min(n,i+2)), xrange(max(0,j-1),min(m,j+2))

                for y in Y:
                    for x in X:

                        if c[y,x] == 2:
                            forest[i,j] = 2                        
    return forest


def canburn(forest):    

    n,m=forest.shape
    c = np.copy(forest)

    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(m):

            if c[i,j] == 1:

                Y, X = xrange(max(0,i-1),min(n,i+2)), xrange(max(0,j-1),min(m,j+2))

                for y in Y:
                    for x in X:

                        if c[y,x] == 2:
                            return True                      
    return False


def forestfire(forest):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    movie = []    

    # Colormap
    red, green, blue = [(1,0,0,1)], [(0,1,0,1)], [(0,0,1,1)]   

    colors = np.vstack((blue, green, red))
    mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)

    # Initialization
    k = 0

    forest = spreadfire(forest)

    im = plt.imshow(forest, animated=True, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", origin='lower')
    movie.append([im])

    # Fire propagation
    while canburn(forest):
        k += 1
        print k

        forest = spreadfire(forest)

        im = plt.imshow(forest, animated=True, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", origin='lower')
        movie.append([im])

    return animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, movie, blit=True, repeat_delay=100)



ani = forestfire(setfire(constructforest(101,101,0.4),50,50))

ani.save("forestfire_test.mp4", writer = 'ffmpeg', fps=5, dpi=500)
```

#### EDIT

As requested by @Y.Luo by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest in the comments I downgraded matplotlib to 2.0.0 and I changed the framerate of the animation but `forestfire_test.mp4` still displays a blank plot.

Here are my settings:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Works fine with `Python 2.7.13; matplotlib 2.0.0`. What is the specific version you've been using? Did you get any errors? Does "blank plot" mean a initial plot with your tree or nothing?

Comment: I could reproduce the issue partially. I do get an mp4 video, but it stops after some frames and then shows the same frame over and over again. Using then a higher framerate (in my case `fps=6` instead of `5` was enough) produced a complete video.

Comment: Sorry I'm late, my Python version is `Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]` and my matplotlib version is `matplotlib 2.0.2`. I also changed the framerate many times but nothing changes. I will downgrade matplotlib to 2.0.0 and see what happens.