# Matplotlib : How to save an animation after clicking on the button that launches the animation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, cellular-automata

I made a little forest fire animation. My codes are at the end of the question.

The code `forestfire.py` contains the functions that will spread the fire to all the `forest`. Then `forestfire_test.py` import `forestfire.py` as `ff` and from there I can set the `forest` on fire with my mouse by clicking on the array displayed by matplotlib.

Here is some information before I ask my question :

- No tree : `forest[i,j] = 0`
- A tree : `forest[i,j] = 1`
- A tree on fire : `forest[i,j] = 2`
- Hashes : `forest[i,j] = 3`

Basically what happens is that `forest` is  2 dimensional array of size **n** by **m** made of numbers between 1 and 0. The function `onclick` sets on fire the `forest` and while the `forest` still has trees on fire the function `spreadfire` spread the fire.

With the function `onclick` I can set the forest on fire (if I click on the array the trees will become red) and with the function `start` I can execute the code thanks to the button `Start`.

Now the issue is that the first time I execute the code it does not know what ani is (`NameError: global name 'ani' is not defined`) – which is normal because I call the animation `ani` (by trying to save it) before I even call the function start. But if I try to save `ani` in the function `start` I get a blank plot –  which is also normal.

To sum up I need to save the animation after the function `start` is called but I can’t save it at the end of the function `start` otherwise I will get a blank plot. Can someone tell me what should I do?

PS : I use Spyder and the IPython console And please tell me if my explanations are not clear enough.

#### forestfire_test.py

```
import forestfire as ff
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm

from matplotlib.widgets import Button, Cursor


global forest
forest = np.random.rand(100,100)


# Colormap
greens = cm.Greens(np.linspace(0,1, num=50))
greensfill = cm.Greens(np.ones(25))
red = [(1,0,0,1)]*len(greens)
gray = [(.5,.5,.5,1)]*len(greens)

colors = np.vstack((greens, greensfill, red, gray))
mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)

# Figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
fig.subplots_adjust(right=1.3)
im = ax.imshow(forest, animated=True, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", origin='lower', vmin=0, vmax=3.5)


ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.tick_params(direction='out')


cursor = Cursor(ax, useblit=True, color='red', linewidth=1)
plt.show()


# Coordinates
def onclick(event):
    x, y = int(event.xdata), int(event.ydata)
    forest[y,x] = 2.
    im.set_data(forest)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)   


# Start button
def start(event):
    global ani
    ani = ff.forestfire(forest)

button_ax = plt.axes([0.15, 0.45, 0.2, 0.1])
button = Button(button_ax, 'Start', color='lightgrey', hovercolor='grey')
button.on_clicked(start)


# Animation
ani.save("forestfire_test.mp4", writer = 'ffmpeg', fps=5, dpi=500)
```

#### forestfire.py

```
from random import random

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import choice

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm

import matplotlib.animation as animation



def hazard(p):
    r=random()
    assert p>=0 and p<=1
    return r <= p


def chg(case):
    if case > 1.:
        return 1.
    else:
        return case


def spreadfire(forest):    

    n,m=forest.shape
    c = np.copy(forest)

    L = xrange(3)

    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(m):

            if c[i,j] == 2.:

                sautX, sautY = choice([0,1,40],p=[0.4999,0.4999,0.0002]), choice([0,1,40],p=[0.4999,0.4999,0.0002])
                Y, X = xrange(max(0,i-1-sautY),min(n,i+2+sautY),sautY+1), xrange(max(0,j-1-sautX),min(m,j+2+sautX),sautX+1)    

                for y1,y2 in zip(Y,L):
                    for x1,x2 in zip(X,L):

                        if hazard(chg(c[y1,x1])):
                            forest[y1,x1] = 2.

    return forest


def forestfire(forest):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    movie, hashes = [], []

    # Colormap
    greens = cm.Greens(np.linspace(0,1, num=50))
    greensfill = cm.Greens(np.ones(25))
    red = [(1,0,0,1)]*len(greens)
    gray = [(.5,.5,.5,1)]*len(greens)

    colors = np.vstack((greens, greensfill, red, gray))
    mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)

    # Initialization
    k = 0
    firefront = 5


    forest = spreadfire(forest)

    c = np.copy(forest)
    c[np.where(c==2.)] = 3.
    hashes.append(c)

    im = plt.imshow(forest, animated=True, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", origin='lower', vmin=0, vmax=3.5)
    movie.append([im])

    # Fire propagation
    while np.count_nonzero(forest == 2.) != 0:
        k += 1
        print k

        if k < firefront:

            forest = spreadfire(forest)

            c = np.copy(forest)
            c[np.where(c==2.)] = 3.
            hashes.append(c)

            im = plt.imshow(forest, animated=True, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", origin='lower', vmin=0, vmax=3.5)
            movie.append([im])

        else:        
            forest = spreadfire(forest)

            c = np.copy(forest)
            c[np.where(c==2.)] = 3.
            hashes.append(c)

            forest[np.where(hashes[0]==3.)] = 3.
            im = plt.imshow(forest, animated=True, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", origin='lower', vmin=0, vmax=3.5)
            movie.append([im])
            hashes.remove(hashes[0])

    return animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, movie, blit=True, repeat_delay=100)
```

Comment: You need to move the `ani.save` inside the `start` function. `plt.show` should then only be called at the end of the script. Apart from then setting the framerate to 6 as said previously this is then working fine for me, running as a script (on python 2.7.10, matplotlib 2.0.2) in the sense that after clicking the start button the animation is saved as mp4 file to the current directory.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the framerate didn't change anything but plt.show did. If you post the answer I'll validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here, as mentionned in the comment:

1. You need to move the `ani.save` inside the start function. This is because `ani` will only be defined once the start button is pressed.
2. `plt.show` should then only be called at the end of the script.

This is then working fine for me, running as a script (on python 2.7.10, matplotlib 2.0.2) in the sense that after clicking the start button, the animation is saved as mp4 file to the current directory.

Apart from that I needed to set the framerate to 6 or above as commented in a  [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134356/matplotlib-live-animation-works-fine-but-displays-a-blank-plot-when-being-save?rq=1).